# Converting Bash shell scripts to batch files

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am trying to convert a shell script to a batch file line by line and command by command. However, I cannot seem to get around the following line. Any help appreciated.

```
OPTS="%OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=file:.\log4j.properties"
```

Comment: It appears to be syntax for an executable: is it available in the target system?  Some extra context may help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know linux shell but I think the equivalent is this:

```
Set "OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=.\log4j.properties"
```

Then you can load the stored ...Options¿? like an argument:

```
Start Application.exe %OPTS%
```

**".\"** means the current directory of your script, ensure if **"file:.\"** means the same in linux OS.